# How RODBC add the dynamic date for DB2, need a single quote

Tags: r, string, date, db2, rodbc

I add a dynamic date `'", dt, "'`for my code as follow.

I first put the date as string, and then paste into sqlQuery.

```
today<-Sys.Date() 
monthStart <- function(x) { 
x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
x$mday <- 1
as.Date(x)
}
dt_date<-monthStart(today)-1 
dt<-as.character(dt_date) 

df<-sqlQuery(db2,paste("
Select SUM_DATE from database where SUM_DATE= '", dt, "'
"), as.is=TRUE)`
```

but the error says:

```
[1] "22007 -180 [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007\r\n"
```

I am sure the date format should be `'2018-02-28'`
so if I replace `'", dt, "'` with `'2018-02-28'`, the code above works fine.

I guess it is because R string is double quote but db2 wants a single quote. So how can I solve this problem?

Any idea is appreciated and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default in `paste` uses `sep=" "`, your query reads with such spaces in the date value:

```sql
Select SUM_DATE from database where SUM_DATE= ' 2018-02-28 ';
```

To resolve consider either `paste0` or `paste` with `sep=""`

```
sql <- paste0("Select SUM_DATE from database where SUM_DATE= '", dt, "'")
df <- sqlQuery(db2, sql, as.is=TRUE)
```

Even better is to use parameterization, the industry best practices in running SQL in application layer like R and you can do so with extension package, [RODBCext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html).

```
library(RODBCext)

df <- sqlExecute(db2, "Select SUM_DATE from database where SUM_DATE = ?", dt, fetch=TRUE)
```

Comment: oh, I didnt realize that there are spaces between quote and actual date. but it actually works for my other databases, like oracle, do you have any idea why it just not works for db2?

Comment: Other DBs might `trim()` values passed into dates.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try sprintf(), since you will still need single quote around your date.

```
 df<-sqlQuery(db2,sprintf("Select SUM_DATE from database where SUM_DATE='%s'",dt))
```